# How do I get a straight line in \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Koch snowflake]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

The following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,decoration=Koch snowflake]
\draw decorate{ (0,0) -- (3,0) };
\draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (3,-1) }};
\draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (3,-2) }}};
\draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (3,-3) }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives me the following picture:

[image]

To emphasize the initiator and I'd like the first figure to be a straight line, like on this picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vanderbilt.edu](http://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/psychology/cogsci/chaos/workshop/Fig4.7.GIF))</sub>

The problem is that I don't quite understand what the numbers `{ (0,0) -- (3,0) }` mean, and being new to TeX, I also don't know where to look it up.

Comment: Cartesian coordinates of points.

Comment: `\draw (0,1) -- (3,1);`?

Comment: @Leo, in case you were just reading the literally first page of the PGF/TikZ documentation, I really recommend reading through the first tutorial, and everything will be very clear.

Comment: @Sigur an answer maybe?

Comment: @Turion: you're perfectly right. For some reason I assumed that an answer would require knowing what `[decoration=Koch snowflake]` is about and I couldn't find anything except examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by comments.