# Fractals in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, decorations, fractals

How to draw a shape like below using fractals in tikZ?

[image: Fractal Triangle]

Comment: not the same one but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/how-to-create-a-sierpinski-triangle-in-latex

Comment: This is not a "please od it all for me" site. What have you got so far?

Comment: This might help you to get started: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/fractals/

Comment: 'od' --> 'do' `;)`

Comment: Like the [Koch snowflake curve](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193675/how-do-i-get-a-straight-line-in-begintikzpicturedecoration-koch-snowflake)?

Comment: Related: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3960/fraktale-mit-pgfplots (in german, though)

Comment: Related: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/6867/wie-kann-man-ein-ifs-fraktal-iterated-function-system-mit-latex-erzeugen (in german, though)

Comment: Why do you want to draw it with fractals particularly?

Comment: I vote to close unless you can add a specific TeX question beyond "How to do this whole thing?"

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't resist.  This [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) version might give you some ideas of how to do things in TikZ if that's your chosen approach.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef decorate(expr line, ttl) = 
   if ttl > 0:
     save m, p; 
     pair m; m = point 1/6 of line rotatedabout(point 1/2 of line, 90);
     path p; p = point 0 of line -- m -- point 1 of line;
     draw p;
     decorate(subpath(0,1) of p, ttl-1);
     decorate(subpath(1,2) of p, ttl-1);
   fi
enddef;

beginfig(1);
n = 3;
path base; base = for i=1 upto n: up scaled 4cm rotated (360/n*i) -- endfor cycle;
draw base;
for i=1 upto length(base):
  decorate(subpath (i-1,i) of base, 4);   
endfor
endfig;
end.
```

If you crank up the number of iterations a bit you get some simple fractal self-similarities. Here is it with 5 sides in the base shape and using a depth of 12.

[image]